# Why input stream object fails after reading file to the end?

Tags: c++, ifstream

Here is the code . 
It is giving the EXACT output as shown below means it is reading the file.
But it is also showing `fails` as you can see it means `fin.fails()` is `true`.
I want to know why this is true although i am successful in reading the file.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   ifstream fin;
    fin.open("pro.txt");
    char ch;
    int data;
    while(!fin.eof())//!(fin >> ch).eof()
    {
        fin.get(ch);
        cout<<ch;
        if(fin.fail()) {
            cout<<"fails";
        break;
        }
    }
    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0);
    int pos=(int)fin.tellg();
    cout<<"\n this is :"<<pos;
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}

Output is :
this is my name
fails
this is 0

Contents of pro.txt:
this is my name
```

Don't know why this is happening!

Comment: [OT] Do not use `eof` for a loop condition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: then what to use ? and also why the fin.fails is true

Comment: The proper way is to use the read operation.

Comment: Try `while (fin >> ch)`, but as it doesn't output anything, it's probable that your opening fails (for example if the current working directory is not the one you expect).

Comment: why he marked this question as duplicate ?

Comment: this is a complete different question from the above mentioned

Comment: @AkashKabir Duplicates aren't about questions, but the answers that can be found there. If you don't think that answers your question, edit it and explain exactly why not.

Comment: Where did you read to use `while(!fin.eof())`? We need to correct that book.

Comment: I am just saying this because i can't relate my answer to the answer given in that question . It will nice if you answer my question with reference to that question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is working correctly!! better u can use it  tooo but i just wanted to ask why the fin.fails() is true.

Comment: @Christophe     `while(fin>>ch)` working but it is skipping one letter each time i.e this is my name   output: hssyae      WHY?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry but now i read it and my file `pro.txt` is in same working directory

Comment: output is showing ! this means it is reading the file but also failing after reading it ... now i think my question answer is different

Comment: @AkashKabir As mentioned edit your question to provide a [MCVE], and explain any errors exactly.

Comment: `fin>>ch` not showing white spaces can you provide another way of reading file with whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

Still can't find why the `fin.fails()` is true because i think no one willing to
But i figured out to read white spaces and file without making `fin.fails()` =`true` .
just replace the `while(!fin.eof())` with `while(fin.get(ch))` and remove the `fin.get(ch)` present in while body -> this was the reason why my output was skipping one character for each read.. this i had mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in comments too, but you told me I was wrong. :smh:

Comment: i didn't said that ! i know that was my fault and `fin>>ch` don't manages white spaces try it yourself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following: Reading the last character in your file with `get` will **not** set the `eofbit`, so the call to `fin.eof()` in your `while` condition still returns `false` after you read the last character of the file inside the loop body. Then during the iteration following the read of the last character you try to read another character inside the loop body, even though there is no character to read anymore. This will set the `eofbit` **and** the `failbit` as per [specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) of `get`.

TL;DR: Reading over the end of a file is supposed to set the `failbit`.